# How do i handle errors in nativescript app?

Tags: javascript, nativescript

i am done coding my App and i will be publishing soon. Right now, when there is an error in the app, it stops the whole app and shows StackTrace errors. please how can i stop this.
i saw a solution relating to this on the [nativescript website](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/error-handling)

this is what i have tried below

```
import * as traceModule from "tns-core-modules/trace";
const errorHandler = {
    handlerError(err) {

    }
};
traceModule.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
```

NB: i use nativescript core (javascript)

Comment: You may read the disable uncaught exception section in same document to handle the exception differently.

Answer (score 1):

saw this solution on stackoverflow

When an android application is built in release mode;

```
tns build android --release --key-store-path [path] --key-store-password [pw] --key-store-alias [alias] --key-store-alias-pw [pw]
```

The app will automatically disable the stack trace screen on Android. By default the tns build android will be building debug mode applications.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that. Google Play requires debugging mode disabled anyways, just build a release. FYI: If you have errors that crashes the app, you should fix those instead just release an app with these kind of issues